# Dimension of Subspace $x^T(J-I)x=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the maximum dimension of any subspace of vectors (in the reals) satisfying $$
x^T(J-I) x=0?
$$
This is on the reals. My conjecture is that its less than two.

edit: I is the identity matrix and J is the all ones matrix of same (finite) dimension.

I managed to sketch an outline for start of a proof that any two vectors are either orthogonal or linearly dependent:
Let $x,y$ be two nonzero vectors in some subspace $S$ satisfying the equation. For any scalars $\alpha, \beta$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
0&= (\alpha x+\beta y)^T(J-I)(\alpha x+\beta y)\\&=\alpha^2 x^T(J-I) x+ 2 \alpha \beta x^T(J-I) y+\beta^2 y^T(J-I) y\\&= 2 \alpha \beta x^T(J-I) y
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Is that really a subspace? It is a space, but what makes it a subspace? Seems to not be closed under addition.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are both correct, in that case I've edited the question to be about subspaces that satisfy the equation. There should be no issue now.

Comment: You've fixed enough I've cleaned up my comments and upvoted. But it's still not clear to me how you go from $x^T\alpha x+x^T\beta y=0\,$ to $\,x^T\beta y=0$. Also your logic instead seems to be saying that *if* solutions are dependent, *then* they are orthogonal, since the hypothesis you started with ($\alpha x+\beta y=0$) is that they were dependent. That's not the same as saying solutions are either orthogonal or dependent.

Comment: @elemelons Ah, I've cleaned it up more more in lines of what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case of $n=1$ is trivially $1-$dimensional so I assume $n\geq 2$.  The problem is, consider the quadratic form $q:\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $q\big(\mathbf x\big) = \mathbf x^T\big(J-I\big)\mathbf x$ and we are asked about the maximal dimension of subspace $W\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ such that $q\big(W\big) = \big\{0\big\}$ (i.e. total isotropy).

The key idea behind this problem is Sylvester's Law of Inertia and the **signature** of the matrix $\big(J-I\big)$, which limits the size of a totally isotropic subspace.  That is the form/matrix has **signature** of $\big(1,n-1\big)$ (check $q$ is positive on all non-zero vectors in the subspace generated by the ones vector and negative on all non-zero vectors in said space's orthogonal complement).  **Spectral Theorem tells us** this means $\big(J-I\big)$ has eigenvalues of the form $\lambda_n \leq \dots\leq \lambda_3 \leq \lambda_2 \lt 0 \lt \lambda_1$.

Suppose for contradiction that we find a (at least) 2 dimensional totally isotropic subspace with basis vectors $\mathbf x_1, \mathbf x_2$.  For avoidance of doubt this means  $\mathbf x_1^T\big(J-I\big)\mathbf x_2 = \frac{1}{2}\Big(q\big(\mathbf x_1+\mathbf x_2\big)-q\big(\mathbf x_1\big)-q\big(\mathbf x_2\big)\Big)=\frac{1}{2}\Big(0-0-0\Big)=0$.

Now collect these vectors in matrix
$X:=\bigg[\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathbf x_1 &  \mathbf x_{2}
\end{array}\bigg] =QR$ where the right hand side is "thin" QR factorization ($Q$ is injective and $R$ is invertible).
$\mathbf 0 = X^T\big(J-I\big)X = R^T Q^T\big(J-I\big)QR=Q^T\big(J-I\big)Q$

$\implies \lambda_{n}\leq 0\leq \lambda_2$
by Cauchy Eigenvalue Interlacing.  Thus $0\leq \lambda_2 \lt 0$ which is a contradiction.

Since we can always find a 1 dimensional (totally) isotropic subspace by selecting a standard basis vector, conclude the maximal dimension of a totally isotropic subspace is always $=1$.